# C# invoking CPP function with unknown number of args from CPP

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, variadic-functions

i have a function in CPP with the following prototype:

```
char* complexFunction(char* arg1, ...);
```

i import it from a C# using DLLImport attribute.
the questions are: 
how do i define the prototype in the C# (under the DLLImport attribute)?
how do i pass the arguments to this function?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is called variadic function. The information on P/Invoke support for them is rather scarce, here's what I found out.

I couldn't find a way to directly `DllImport` a function with variable number of arguments. I had to `DllImport` *all variations* of arguments as different overloads.

Let's take for example [wsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550(VS.85).aspx). It has the following prototype in `winuser.h`:

```
int WINAPIV wsprintf(      
    LPTSTR lpOut,
    LPCTSTR lpFmt,
    ...);
```

It can be used from C# like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class C {

  // first overload - varargs list is single int
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  static extern int wsprintf(
    [Out] StringBuilder buffer,
    string format,
    int arg);

  // second overload - varargs list is (int, string)
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  static extern int wsprintf(
    [Out] StringBuilder buffer,
    string format,
    int arg1,
    string arg2);

  public static void Main() {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    int result = wsprintf(buffer, "%d + %s", 42, "eggs!");
    Console.WriteLine("result: {0}\n{1}", result, buffer);
  }
}
```

Now to address your `complexFunction`.

```
char* complexFunction(char* arg1, ...);
```

Its varargs list should be addressed in the same way: by providing all useful overloads. But there is also another complication - return type. I assume that `complexFunction` allocates and returns array of `char`. In this case it's most likely that the caller is responsible for array's deallocation. To allow for this you should import deallocation routine as well, let's call it `void free(void*)`.

Assuming all that's been assumed, C# code using `complexFunction` would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class C {

  [DllImport("your.dll",
             CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
             CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
  static extern IntPtr complexFunction(
    string format,
    int arg1, int arg2);

  [DllImport("your.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  static extern void free(IntPtr p);

  public static void Main() {
    IntPtr pResult = complexFunction("%d > %s", 2, 1);
    string sResult = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pResult);
    free(pResult);
    Console.WriteLine("result: {0}", sResult);
  }
}
```